# Rails: how to create maintainable HTML structures (that are defined in one place and used wherever needed)?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm in the process of creating a page that has a lot of static content. The content is wrapped in always the same HTML structure, e.g.:

```
# SLIM file
article
  h1 This is the title

  .content
    p Some content

  footer Copyright note
```

Often times the design changes, and I have to update the HTML structure to e.g. something like adding a class to the `article` element:

```
article.some_class
  h1 This is the title

  .content
    p Some content

  footer Copyright note
```

Now: it's pretty cumbersome to search and replace all occurrences of this structure. So it would be nice to build the structure dynamically using a helper, something like this:

```
= article do |a|
  = a.title do
    | This is the title

  = a.content do
    p Some content

  = a.footer do
    | Copyright note
```

This way the definition exists at only one place, so it can be easily changed whenever I like.

It would be pretty basic to build a plain ruby helper like the one above, but maybe there are other patterns or even gems providing such functionality?

For very simple cases I could use partials, but this becomes pretty cumbersome when the contents become more complex:

```
render 'article', title: 'This is the title', content: '<p>Some conent</p>'.html_safe, footer: 'Copyright note'
```

As you can see, `content: '<p>Some conent</p>'.html_safe` is already too complex.

Comment: Your examples don't do a very good job of showing what your actual problem is. Partials are a perfect fit for what you've shown here. It would be much more helpful to see your actual code than contrived examples.

Comment: No, IMHO partials don't fit here, unless you can pass an object to it. But because I don't have an object, I would have to pass every part of the content as a variable itself, which doesn't work very well, when the contents are complex.

Comment: The contents aren't complex in your examples. Answering your question depends on seeing what the actual, complex contents are, not contrived examples.

Comment: I updated my question. With complex contents I mean lots of HTML which can't be passed as a variable easily, but can be passed perfectly as blocks to a helper, but only one block can be passed this elegantly.

Comment: Where are these values coming from? If you have the values hard-coded in your controller, as in your example, then that's the first thing you ought to refactor. At the very least you could have a method in your controller (or a utility module somewhere else) that returns a Hash with the `:title`, `:content`, and `:footer` keys, which would reduce your code to `render 'article', method_with_a_useful_name`.

Comment: The values are very arbitrary. Think about being in process of creating a big site with much content, which doesn't come from a DB at the moment (maybe it will sometime, but for the first release, it doesn't). I agree with you that one could try to put them in some hash and pass them to a partial, but it's not very beautiful to pack long HTML strings into a hash. So I still think my example above makes sense, and a small helper that accepts a block and passes an object to the block which itself accepts different messages is a good idea. I will try to add a basic implementation.

Comment: It seems that Ryan Bates talked about something very similar in his RailsCast 213 "Calendar revised". I stumbled over it when searching for more info about this topic, in the following StackOverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849195

Comment: I have added my own response. Please take a look at it and tell me what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with my own solution, based on [Ryan Bates' excellent screen cast "Calendars (revised)"](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised).

```
# article_helper.rb
module ArticleHelper
  def article(&block)
    Article.new(self, block).render
  end

  class Article < Struct.new(:view, :callback)
    delegate :content_tag, to: :view

    def render
      content_tag :article do
        view.capture(self, &callback)
      end
    end

    def title(&block)
      content_tag :div, class: 'title' do
        view.capture(self, &block)
      end
    end

    def slogan(&block)
      content_tag :div, class: 'slogan' do
        view.capture(self, &block)
      end
    end

    def content(&block)
      content_tag :div, class: 'content' do
        view.capture(self, &block)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Somewhere in a template:

```
= article do |a|
  = a.title do
    ' titttttel with a date:
    date 12-24-2014

  = a.slogan do
    ' This is a really
    strong' cool
    ' article!

  = a.content do
    p some paragraph

    ul
      li item 1
      li item 2
```

Results in the following HTML:

```
<article>
  <div class="title">
    titttttel with a date: <date>12-24-2014</date>
  </div>
  <div class="slogan">
    This is a really <strong>cool</strong> article!
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>some paragraph</p>
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</article>
```

While this example may not look pretty fancy and useful in the first place, think about this: you are implementing a design that's not final yet and prone to changes again and again. You want to use the `article` design component at various places throughout your whole application. Whenever a change of the layout requires a change at the HTML code, you would have to do the change wherever you copied&pasted the component's HTML.

By using a helper like this, you have your code defined at one single place, and maintaining it is very easy.

Another problem that occurs a lot is that an HTML prototype is rather complex and your co-workers sometimes fail to implement it properly in their own work. With this helper approach you can provide nested block calls and therewith help your co-workers to avoid creating any invalid HTML strucutre:

```
# grid_helper.rb
module GridHelper
  def grid(&block)
    Grid.new(self, block).render
  end

  class Grid < Struct.new(:view, :callback)
    delegate :content_tag, to: :view

    def render
      view.capture(self, &callback)
    end

    def three_columns(&block)
      ThreeColumns.new(view, block).render
    end

    class ThreeColumns < Grid
      def render
        content_tag :section, class: 'three_columns' do
          view.capture(self, &callback)
        end
      end

      def first_column(&block)
        content_tag :div, class: 'first_column' do
          view.capture(self, &block)
        end
      end

      def second_column(&block)
        content_tag :div, class: 'second_column' do
          view.capture(self, &block)
        end
      end

      def third_column(&block)
        content_tag :div, class: 'third_column' do
          view.capture(self, &block)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Somewhere in a view:

```
= grid do |g|
  = g.three_columns do |tc|
    = tc.first_column do
      | This is the content of the first column!

    = tc.second_column do
      | This is the content of the center column!

    = tc.third_column do
      | This is the content of the third column!
```

Results in the following HTML:

```
<section class="three_columns">
  <div class="first_column">This is the content of the first column!</div>
  <div class="second_column">This is the content of the center column!</div>
  <div class="third_column">This is the content of the third column!</div>
</section>
```

I think this would be very helpful in creating complex HTML structures in large projects, especially when there are many developers and spreading the knowledge of recent changes to the HTML prototype is a real pain for everyone.

While it is pretty cumbersome to write such structures like the ones above, it would be great to have some DSL which would convert e.g. SLIM files into such helpers.

Disclaimer: I know that helpers are pretty slow when overused. So once the design is legislated, one could easily search&replace the helper calls with the HTML structures. I could even imagine some sort of templates compilation during deployment or in production mode.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of thing you should use a layout. If it is the default HTML structure for your site just put it in `app/layouts/application.slim` and replace `p Some content` with `yield`:

```
article
  h1 This is the title

  .content
    yield

  footer Copyright note
```

Then in your specific slim files you just put.

```
p Some content
```

If you want different layouts in different cases you can pass a layout when rendering the page. In your controller you woul put:

```
render layout: some_other_layout
```

The default layout is `application.slim`. It is also possible to have nested layouts. Read more in the [Layouts and Rendering guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) that cover most of this stuff.

UPDATE: it is possible to use partials with layouts which will be perfect for you needs in this case. Put your layout in another file called `common_layout.slim` or something. When you want to insert this common part make the call in your main slim template:

```
render :specific_part, layout: common_layout
```

And for some other part of code you go

```
render :some_other_part, layout: common_layout
```

There must be `specific_part.slim` and `some_other_part.slim` available somewhere also with the specific markup. I also believe it is possible to inline the specific markup like so:

```
render layout: common_layout do 
    "<b>some markup here</b>"
```

if you don't want to have a slim file for each little part.

Comment: I'm not talking about layouts here, but about pieces of HTML that can be used wherever liked within a page.

Comment: it is indeed possible to use layouts with partials which would be perfect for your case. It is all in the documentation I added a link to. Nice with a downvote when someone is trying to help. :-( but maybe it was someone else....

Comment: Maybe I don't really understand what you mean. I'm sorry for the downvote, I undid it. Could you please explain a little more what you mean? In the documentation, I don't find much related to my problem in the "nested layouts" section. Maybe take into account that I may have more than a single place where I want to put complex HTML, so the single `yield` would not be enough.

Comment: I added how to do it with partials in the answer. Hope it gets clearer! The idea is to reuse the layout but not the particulars so your concern should not be a problem.

Comment: This is interesting stuff. But this doesn't appreciate my need to have many parts with complex HTML within one big structure (e.g. a title, a body, some comments, etc.). The appending block is interesting, but one can only send one block (if even, didn't try it out myself) to a partial.